# tail call optimization in lua

Tags: lua, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Lua claims that it implement tail call properly thus no stack needs to be maintained for each call thus allow infinite recursion, I tried to write a *sum* function, one is not tail call, and one is tail call:

**non tailcall version**

```
function sum(n)
    if n > 0 then
        return n + sum(n-1)
    end
end

print(sum(1000000))
```

stackoverflow as expected.

**tailcall version**

```
function sum2(accu, n)
    if n > 0 then
        accu.value = accu.value + n
        sum2(accu, n-1)
    end
end
local accu = {value = 0}
sum2(accu, 1000000)
print(accu.value)
```

I suppose there would be no stackoverflow in this case as it is a tailcall, but it still failed due to stackoverflow:

```
/bin/lua/5.1.4/bin/lua: tailcall.lua:13: stack overflow
stack traceback:
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        ...
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:13: in function 'sum2'
        tailcall.lua:17: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

So is lua really support tail call optimization, or my function is actually not tail call here?

I am using lua 5.1.4 on redhat 5

Comment: From Roberto Ierusalimshy (one of Lua's author): "In Lua, only a call with the form return func(args) is a tail call."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tail call in Lua **must** have the following form

```
return fct(args)
```

So your tail call version must be rewritten as:

```
function sum2(accu, n)
  if n > 0 then
    accu.value = accu.value + n
    return sum2(accu, n-1) --< note the return here
  end
end
```

Comment: oh, yea - that is exactly the reason! just an extra "return", thanks prapin!

Comment: but how could lua can't figure out this is actually a tail call:)

Comment: "*how could lua can't figure out this is actually a tail call*" I don't understand what you just asked.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I know the reason, for lua, 'sum2(accu, n-1)' is same as 'sum2(accu, n-1); return', not 'return sum2(accu, n-1)', so it is apparent not a tail call without a return.

Comment: As explained in "Program in Lua" part 1 chap 6, to be considered a tail call the return should be followed directly by a function call not any expression.

So:

`return n+sum(n-1)`

Is understood by Lua as a operation between `n` with the result of `sum(n-1)`. To be a tail call Lua expects that the return be directly of a call to a function.

Observe this:

`return somefunc(n+1)`

In this case, Lua understands that is a call with the parameter n+1, so proceeds as tail call.

Answer (score -1):

As has already been said, the only correct tail call syntax is `return f(...)`

That's because `f() ; return` is not the same as `return f()`: the former requires a final operation after calling `f` : drop its results to ensure nothing is returned.

> but how could lua can't figure out this is actually a tail call

Because lua is a very "dynamic" language: in

```lua
function sum2(accu, n)
    if n > 0 then
        accu.value = accu.value + n
        sum2(accu, n-1)
    end
end
```

`sum2` is not calling *itself*, it's calling the **global variable** `"sum2"` (or equivalent *upvalue* if declared `local`)

And this variable could become a function returning values, in which case emitting a tail call bytecode would be incorrect.

In other words: whether `f` makes a tail call is knowledge that is inaccessible to the compiler, and will only be confirmed at runtime, unless you use the unbreakable syntax `return f(...)`